# Closure Library ondevicemotion never fired

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library, motionevent

Dear Javascript programmers,

Google's Closure Library is always good for driving people crazy. I hope you can help me on this issue:

I want to catch the `ondevicemotion`-Event by javascript within a function within the Closure lib.
Without Closure everything works fine with the following code which I grabbed from this page (thanks to the author): http://www.peterfriese.de/how-to-use-the-gyroscope-of-your-iphone-in-a-mobile-web-app/

The following snippet shows "my" code:

```
if (window.DeviceMotionEvent != undefined) {
    console.log("DME");
    window.ondevicemotion = function(e) {
    console.log("ODM");

    // handle events like e.rotationRate
    ...
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in a standalone html page. Both `console.log`s are triggered.

In contrast, Closure seems to have a problem with `window.ondevicemotion = function(e) {` because the console logs "DME" but not "ODM".
There are no compiler warnings or errors.

Has anybody recognized such a problem, too? I sadly have no idea why Closure acts so stupid (more probably ***I*** am so stupid). ;-)

Thanks for reading! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does your externs file define `window.ondevicemotion`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I now use bracket notation. The externs file defines `window.DeviceMotionEvent;`

Comment: filing a bug against closure to add `window.ondevicemotion` might be a good way to let them know that it's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running in ADVANCED_COMPILATION, the Closure Compiler minimized and obfuscated `window.ondevicemotion` for me, so I'll assume that is your problem as well. There are two ways to step around this:

### **1. Use bracket notation to set / access the property.**

The Closure Computer will not rename any properties that are referenced via the bracket notation. The following should not get obfuscated (though, potentially, it could get rewritten as `window.ondevicemotion`):

```
window['ondevicemotion'] = function(event) { ... }
```

### **2. Use an [extern](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs) to let the compiler know not to rename this property.**

Similar to the situation above, the Closure Compiler takes a hint and doesn't rewrite the property, leaving it as is. This, however, has a nice benefit of giving you some type checking, since you're defining what the signature of the extern is to the Closure Compiler:

```
/**
 * @param {goog.events.Event} event
 */
window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {};
```

The decision of which one to use is ultimately yours. In this scenario I would most likely go for the second option and only go back to the first if there was some reason you could not use externs.

Comment: I can't believe I was so stupid! Thank you for your help and this explanation! It totally works with the bracket notation. :)